# What combination of genre & type make for excellent combinations when developing a game?

Tags: game-dev-story

In Game Dev Story, sales are boosted when you develop a game with a great Genre/Type combination.

What combinations are considered *great*? In other words, which ones result in the game informing you that the combination will impact sales in a positive manner?

Comment: Add birds, make them angry.

Comment: Perhaps Angrily Jumping Doodle Birds?

Comment: I think *Game Dev Story* was written just to confuse those of us who read gaming.stackexchange.com and gamedev.stackexchange.com!

Comment: @Kevin: Even better *laughs*

Comment: I was about to come and angrily vote to close.  I'm trying hard to incorporate birds into the post, but that would be jumping too far.  As for doodle, I just can't do it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Community Wiki

Because this answer will be one of constant discovery by myself (and possibly other helpful users), I've made this answer a [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/151410) answer. Anyone with the rights to edit it should feel free to contribute based on personal experience or other sourced information. Please make an effort to keep the list in alphabetical order for the sake of easy reference. :)

#### Key

- **Best Combinations** - 'Amazing' according to the game
- *Good Combinations* - 'Not bad' according to the game
- `Positive` - Unknown what the game indicates exactly but they were mentioned to be positive combinations

#### List

- Action

  - **Ninja**
  - *Robot*
  - *Samurai*
  - **Sumo**
- Adventure

  - **Cowboy**
  - **Detective**
  - *Fantasy*
  - `Mushroom`
  - **Mystery**
  - `Pirate`
- Audio Novel

  - **Detective**
  - `Historical`
  - **Horror**
  - *Mystery*
  - **Romance**
- Board

  - *Checkers*
  - **Chess**
- Life

  - **Animal**
  - **Dating**
  - **Mushroom**
  - **Pop Star**
  - Swimsuit
- Motion

  - **Dance**
  - **Fitness**
  - `Mini-skirt`
  - `Ping Pong`
  - **Volleyball**
- Music

  - **Drums**
  - *Movies*
  - *Pop Star*
- Online RPG

  - *Dungeon*
  - *Fantasy*
  - `Game Co.`
  - **Medieval**
  - **Dungeon**
- Online Sim

  - **Architecture**
  - **Mushroom**
  - **Stocks**
- Puzzle

  - **Reversi**
  - *Word*
- Racing

  - *F1 Racing*
  - *Marathon*
  - **Motorsport**
  - **Snowboard**
  - `Swimming`
- RPG

  - *Dungeon*
  - **Fantasy**
  - *Medieval*
  - **Mushroom**
- Shooter

  - *Ninja*
  - **Robot**
  - `War`
- Simulation

  - `Architecture`
  - *Dating*
  - **Game Co.**
  - `Golf`
  - `Lawyer`
  - **Movies**
  - **Mushroom**
  - **Romance**
  - *Stocks*
  - **Town**
  - **Train**
  - **Virtual Pet**
  - **Soccer**
- Table

  - *Checkers*
  - **Mahjong**
- Trivia

  - *Movies*
  - *Mushroom*

#### Sources

Some items on this list were compiled from other sources:

- [Touch Arcade](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?t=70905)
- [GameFAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/610758-game-dev-story/56803032)

Comment: I love Mushroom Life games too!

Comment: I have no objection to you making your answers CW, but I would suggest you not start answers out as CW.  There have been a number of times I've written answers and made them CW, only to be the sole contributor.

Comment: +1: Remember, the popularity of the combinations still depend on the randomly assigned "Popularity Rating" so if you make a game from a good (but unpopular) combination you're not going to sell well.

Comment: @tzenes: That's a good point. I suppose I can always just make things CW in the future either by triggering the edit threshold or marking them when I see tons of comments about alterations.

Comment: @tzenes: CW-ifying an answer also enables low-rep users to make edits, which is good if you want to encourage collaboration.

Comment: @Brant while I agree with that principle, my experience is that it has not encouraged much editing.  Usually users will append comments or write their own answer (even when I've CW'd posts).